# Salesforce Too many soql 101

Tags: dictionary, salesforce, apex, soql

1. It works fine in sandBox but it causes too many soql 101 in Production. I tried to use 2. bulkified map with content distribution link with soql query but it always blocked bulk in MAP. any advise ?
2. Since I tried every thing with list customObject__c=[select... contentdistribution := ..id] but it gives also too many soql 101

@RestResource(urlMapping='/API/V1/notice/*')
global with sharing class API_Notice {

```
@HttpGet(UrlMapping='/API/V1/notice/all')
global static List<String> getNotice(){          
    
    List<Object> senderJson = new List<Object>();  
    
    for (Notice__c a: [SELECT Name, ClosingDate__c,Contents__c, NoticeTypes__c,createddate,OfficialSenders__c,id,(SELECT ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Notice__c]) {               
            List<Object> multipleAcct = new List<Object>();                                       
            NoticeWrapper nw = new NoticeWrapper();
            Set<Id> contentsId = new Set<Id>();             
            List<Object> urls = new List<Object>();
            Set<Id> acctId = new Set<Id>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: a.ContentDocumentLinks){
            if(cdl.ContentDocumentId!=null){
                contentsId.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
             }
        }
        if(a.OfficialSenders__c != null){
            acctId.add(a.OfficialSenders__c);
        }
        
        if(a.id!=null){
            nw.noticeid = a.Id;               
       }     
        if(a.ClosingDate__c != null){   
            nw.ClosingDate = a.ClosingDate__c;                  
       }     
        if(a.NoticeTypes__c != null) {
            nw.NoticeTypes = a.NoticeTypes__c;                
        }    
        if(a.Contents__c !=null){
            nw.Contents = a.Contents__c;            
        }
        if(a.Name !=null) {
            nw.Name = a.Name;         
        }
        if(a.CreatedDate !=null){
            nw.createddate = a.createddate; 
        }  
        if(!acctId.isEmpty()){
             Map<Id,CampaignMember> camplinks = new Map<Id,CampaignMember>([
               select accountid ,CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId IN: acctId 
            ]);                
            if(!camplinks.isEmpty()){
                for(CampaignMember cm : camplinks.values()){
                    multipleAcct.add(cm.AccountId);
                    nw.accountId = multipleAcct;  
                }
            }
        }
         if(!contentsId.isEmpty() && contentsid!=null){
            Map<Id,ContentDistribution> links = new Map<Id,ContentDistribution>([
                select id , distributionPublicURL,ContentDocumentId from contentDistribution where ContentDocumentId IN: contentsId 
            ]); 
            if(!links.isEmpty()){
                for(contentDistribution cdb : links.values()){                          
                    urls.add(cdb.DistributionPublicUrl);
                    nw.DistributionPublicUrl = urls;
                    }
                }              
            }
    
       
        
                                          
        senderJson.add(nw);    
    }
    
    
   
        
    
        List<String> sends = new List<String>();

        for(Object json : senderJson){
            sends.add(String.valueof(json));
        }

        return sends;    
        
    }

@HttpPost
global static List<String> getOneNotice(String Id){
           
    List<Object> urls = new List<Object>();
    List<Object> senderJson = new List<Object>();
    List<Object> multipleAcct = new List<Object>();
    for (Notice__c a: [SELECT Name, ClosingDate__c,Contents__c,OfficialSenders__c, id,(SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Notice__c where id=:id]) {
            Set<Id> acctId = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> contentsId = new Set<Id>();            
            NoticeWrapper nw = new NoticeWrapper();  
            nw.noticeid = a.Id;               
            nw.ClosingDate = a.ClosingDate__c;                
            nw.Contents = a.Contents__c;            
            nw.Name = a.Name;
        
                
            for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: a.ContentDocumentLinks){
                if(cdl.ContentDocumentId!=null){
                    contentsId.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
                }
            }
            if(a.OfficialSenders__c != null){
                acctId.add(a.OfficialSenders__c);
            }
        if(!acctId.isEmpty()){
             Map<Id,CampaignMember> camplinks = new Map<Id,CampaignMember>([
               select accountid ,CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId IN: acctId 
            ]);
            
            if(!camplinks.isEmpty()){
                for(CampaignMember cm : camplinks.values()){
                    multipleAcct.add(cm.AccountId);
                    nw.accountId = multipleAcct;  
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(!contentsId.isEmpty()){
            Map<Id,ContentDistribution> links = new Map<Id,ContentDistribution>([
                select id , distributionPublicURL,ContentDocumentId from contentDistribution where ContentDocumentId IN: contentsId 
            ]);
        
        
        if(!links.isEmpty()){
                for(contentDistribution cdb : links.values()){
                    urls.add(cdb.DistributionPublicUrl);
                    nw.DistributionPublicUrl = urls;
                }
            }
        }
        senderJson.add(nw);    
    }                       
        List<String> sends = new List<String>();
      
        for(Object json : senderJson){
            sends.add(String.valueof(json));
    } 
    return sends;    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The outline of your loop looks like that

```java
for (Notice__c a: [SELECT Name, ClosingDate__c,Contents__c, NoticeTypes__c,createddate,OfficialSenders__c,id,(SELECT ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Notice__c]) {
    // ...
    if(!acctId.isEmpty()){
         Map<Id,CampaignMember> camplinks = new Map<Id,CampaignMember>([
           select accountid ,CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId IN: acctId
        ]);
    }
    if(!contentsId.isEmpty() && contentsid!=null){
        Map<Id,ContentDistribution> links = new Map<Id,ContentDistribution>([
            select id , distributionPublicURL,ContentDocumentId from contentDistribution where ContentDocumentId IN: contentsId
        ]);
    }
    // ...
    senderJson.add(nw);
}
```

So it's 2 queries in each loop iteration, it'll explode after 50 `Notice__c` records. You might be able to optimise it a bit but soon you'll hit different limit like 50K rows queried in single transaction. Past that you'll really need some optimisation, perhaps consider creating mini JSON objects as people edit the data and storing them in a helper text field inside `Notice__c`? Then the API could simply query them ready.

Check if something like this will work better.

```java
// 1. Query all notices.
// 2. Loop through them once to pull the Ids of related records we need to query.
// 3. Query the related stuff once and put it in a map we can easily access.
// 4. Then loop notices again, building the final JSON message.

// 1
List<Notice__c> notices = [SELECT Name, ClosingDate__c,Contents__c, NoticeTypes__c, createddate,
    OfficialSenders__c, id,
        (SELECT ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
    FROM Notice__c];

Map<Id, Campaign> campaigns = new Map<Id, Campaign>();
Map<Id, ContentDocument> contentdocs = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>();

// 2
for (Notice__c a: notices){
    campaigns.put(a.OfficialSenders__c, null);
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: a.ContentDocumentLinks){
        contentdocs.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, null);
    }
}
campaigns.remove(null); // who needs ifs in the loop if you can just remove them once afterwards
contentdocs.remove(null);

// 3a - Campaigns
if(!campaigns.isEmpty()){
    campaigns = new Map<Id, Campaign>([SELECT Id,
            (SELECT AccountId FROM CampaignMembers WHERE AccountId != null)
        FROM Campaign
        WHERE Id IN :campaigns.keyset()]);
}

// 3b - download links
if(!contentdocs.isEmpty()){
    contentdocs = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>([SELECT Id,
        (SELECT distributionPublicURL FROM ContentDistributions WHERE distributionPublicURL != null)
    FROM ContentDocument
    WHERE Id IN :contentdocs.keyset()]);
}

// 4
List<Object> senderJson = new List<Object>();
for (Notice__c a: notices){
    // bla bla, I'm skipping the ifs
    
    Id campaignId = a.OfficialSenders__c;
    // 4a
    if(campaigns.containsKey(campaignId)){
        Campaign c = campaigns.get(campaignId);
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(CampaignMember cm : c.CampaignMembers){
            accountIds.add(cm.AccountId);
        }
        // nw.accountId = accountIds;
    }
    
    // 4b
    if(!a.ContentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()){
        Set<String> urls = new Set<String>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: a.ContentDocumentLinks){
            Id cdi = cdl.ContentDocumentId;
            if(contentdocs.containsKey(cdi)){
                for(ContentDistribution cd : contentdocs.get(cdi).ContentDistributions){
                    urls.add(cd.distributionPublicURL);
                }
            }
        }
        // nw.DistributionPublicUrl = urls;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Really Really appreciate it , i tried that way and it's working thanks